# Moving wicket pagingnavigator to the right

Tags: java, css, wicket

I would like to move the pagingnavigator created by wicket to the right of the screen. As you can see in the picture, I want it near the red circle.
[image: navigator]

I have a html file(BoatOverview.html) consisting of the panel:

```
<wicket:panel>
    <p><table wicket:id="searchresult" class="searchresult"/></p>
</wicket:panel>
```

and a java file(BoatOverview.java) which starts off:

```
class TelledataPanel extends Panel {
    *some existing code*
}
```

From what I have read, you often need to create a custom PagingNavigator to do things like this with wicket. This seems awfully complex when I just want a simple css fix, how do I go about this?

Comment: #searchresult{float:right;} maybe? Full code would be helpul.

Comment: Since your question is more about the CSS, and not directly about Wicket or Java, could you provide final, rendered HTML and CSS? This will give you a more helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you're working with a [DataTable](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/extensions/markup/html/repeater/data/table/DataTable.html) and assuming you're creating your PagingNavigator by using `DataTable.addBottomToolbar(new NavigationToolbar(DataTable))`, you could call `add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("style", "float:right"))` on your NavigationToolbar.

But since you didn't provide any relevant code, this is purely speculative.